# No ip for kasm workspaces

Tags: shell, google-cloud-shell

in google cloud shell i downloaded the kasm workspaces got username and password but inorder to put those i am required to go to the ip address of  cloud shell and i am getting please help me how cacn i access the admin panel?

```
IP ADDR

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:d1:cd:bc:63 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
10: eth0@if11: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:04 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.4/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Why don't use a VM at Cloud Compute? Try the e2-micro ([1 montly instance free](https://cloud.google.com/free)) if it suits your needs.